# Theming individual column of multicolumn field

Tags: 7, views, entities

I have a multicolumn field and I was able to theme all columns to be display as a table, that is working like a charm. When I want to use one of the columns values in a view I rewrite the output of the field and I select the raw value of the column and I can have it display that single value.

The single value I am displaying is a date field so the raw value is YYYY-MM-DD and I would like to format it to mm/dd/yyyy. I have try writing a custom formatter without any luck.

Is there any way I can apply a formatter to the individuals columns of the field?

Comment: have you looked at views php?

Comment: I end up creating a field view template and applying the format there.